# Ruby loop problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a script that is supposed to be writing a list of items to a hash, but for some reason its only placing the last item in the loop in the hash... I have been working on this script all day, so I am pretty sure its something I am just missing.

Here is the script

```
@mr = MediaRating.where("user_id = ?", session['user_credentials_id'])
@mr.each do |rating|
  @m = Media.where("id = ?", rating.media_id)
  @m.each do |m|
    s = Profile.find_by_subscriber_id(m.subscriber_id)
    @h_lang = Language.find_by_code(s.language)
    @history = {m.title => @h_lang.english}
  end
end
```

There are multiple records in the MediaRating table so I know it has to do something with how my loop is. Thanks in advance for the help!

Working code:

```
@mr = MediaRating.where("user_id = ?", session['user_credentials_id'])
@mr.each do |rating|
  @m = Media.find(rating.media_id)
  s = Profile.find_by_subscriber_id(@m.subscriber_id)
  @h_lang = Language.find_by_code(s.language)
  @history[@m.title] = @h_lang.english
end
```

Comment: side note: these finds with id shows that you are not using associations (has_many, belongs_to, ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the last line, you are over-writing the entire @history hash instead of adding a new key/value pair to it. I'm guessing that isn't what you intended. Change this line:

```
@history = {m.title => @h_lang.english}
```

to this:

```
@history[m.title] = @h_lang.english
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple!!! Thanks! I was even able to simplify my loops too! Added new code above.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: Then it is time for you to push that big fat outlined check-mark for this answer.